# How to add text next to checkbox in C# ASP.NET with itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using itextsharp library i want to have a checkbox checked or uncheck next to text.But I am unable to make it work.

[image: image of checkboxes next to tex]

Here is my class constructor.

```
    public pdfCreator(string fileName)
    {
        //Create document  
        pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 15);
        //Create a PDF file in specific path  
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName+".pdf"), FileMode.Create));
        pdfDoc.Open();
    }
```

Here is my method.

```
    public void chkBoxesCreator()
    {
        string FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/WINGDING.TTF";
        string checkBox = "\u00fe";
        string uncheckBox = "o";

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(checkBox, f);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(uncheckBox, f);
        pdfDoc.Add(p);
        pdfDoc.Add(p2);
    }
```

I want text next to checkboxes that i but in blue. How can i get text next to my checkboxes. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I don't have `TextSharp` right now, but see if the `Font` or `BaseFont` classes have an option to set color. Usually it would be named `ForegroundColor` or something with the word 'foreground'.

Comment: I am not interested in change the color I want to know how to add text next to the checkboxes. But thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `PdfAppearance` to set the checkbox(or radioButton, button, etc. )

Here's a full example

```
        public static void chkBoxesCreator()
        {  
           String[] texts = { "one", "two", "three" };

            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            using (var output = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Create))
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output))

            {

                {
                    pdfDoc.Open();                     

                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    Rectangle _rect;
                    PdfFormField _Field1;

                    PdfAppearance[] checkBoxes = new PdfAppearance[2];
                    //set first  checkBox style
                    checkBoxes[0] = cb.CreateAppearance(20, 20);
                    checkBoxes[0].Rectangle(1, 1, 18, 18);
                    checkBoxes[0].Stroke();

                    //set second  checkBox style
                    checkBoxes[1] = cb.CreateAppearance(20, 20);                  
                    checkBoxes[1].Rectangle(1, 1, 18, 18);
                    checkBoxes[1].FillStroke();

                    RadioCheckField _checkbox1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        _rect = new Rectangle(180, 806 - i * 40, 200, 788 - i * 40); //can be any location
                        _checkbox1 = new RadioCheckField(writer, _rect, texts[i], "on");
                        _Field1 = _checkbox1.CheckField;
                        _Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", checkBoxes[0]);
                        _Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", checkBoxes[1]);
                        writer.AddAnnotation(_Field1);

                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(texts[i], new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18)), 210, 790 - i * 40, 0);
                    }

                    cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

**PS**
The only problem i have that i couldn't use your font for some reason i was getting gibberish

**Edit**

You could even change you checkBox fill Color with(and you could make any more crazy thing like create a cross when the checkbox is checked)

```
  checkBoxes[1].SetRGBColorFill(255, 128, 128); //change fill color
```

And the output is(with `SetRGBColorFill`)
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help just one other question the checkboxes are displaying above other text is there a way i can have the checkboxes under the text.

Comment: You can play with the Rectangle dimension and the   ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(... x, y)  and see what fits you