# .Net Core Web Application: How to add radio button or Checkbox in PDF while creating PDF using ITextSharp package version 4.1.6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf

```
  float[] widths = new float[] { 300f, 100f };
    PdfPTable tableLayoutFieldsets = new PdfPTable(widths.Length);
    tableLayoutFieldsets.TotalWidth = 760;
    tableLayoutFieldsets.LockedWidth = true;
    tableLayoutFieldsets.SetWidths(widths);
          
      PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
      var p1 = new Chunk(Convert.ToString("Heading"), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,             fontsize, fontbold, fontcolor));
      cell.AddEle`your text`ment(p1);
      tableLayoutFieldsets.AddCell(cell);
```

This is how im adding text into PDF, but I'm not sure how to add checkbox or radio button with label.

Comment: Hi,Here's a case related with adding checkbox in pdf , does it solve your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877056/how-to-add-text-next-to-checkbox-in-c-sharp-asp-net-with-itextsharp